# using alert() for displaying messages

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert

When you use javascript's `alert()` function within a `PHP` script or `HTML` page to notify the user of something, you usually get a dialogue that says:

```
The page at 123.456.78.9 says:
blah blah blah
```

Is there any way I could eliminate the IP part and simply display my desired message?

Comment: That text is extracted from the URL that you are currently viewing. Assign a domain name to that IP address and your alert window will display the domain name.

Comment: You can use your custom alert messages instead of using good old JavaScript alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript alerts by default gets the current domain name.

You can go for alternating solution of using some custom popups.

There is one jquery plugin Impromptu, in which you can show customized popups. It also has other features.

The basic example of showing it :

```
$.prompt('Hello World');
```

It displays popup with message 'Hello World'

for more details, refer to [this link](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/)

Answer (score 1):

### That is the default title style for Javascript Alert box and you cannot change that

If you want to work with changing the title of alertboxes , you could make use of [`JQuery Alert Dialog`](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).